# Расширение метода clearRect в canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript

Нужна функция,которая в качестве 5-го аргумента метода clearRect принимала значение цвета для удалённой области.
результатом должно быть примерно такое сочетание `c.clearRect(0,0,120,120,color*);`
 color*-значение цвета rgb.
Возможно ли это? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А может просто сделать отрисовку прямоугольника fillRect. Потому как clearRect "очищает" область, делая её прозрачной.

Comment: На девелоперских страницах браузеров существует вся информация с доступными командами js, к примеру: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes
http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/

Comment: Спасибо.Я знаком.
А если мне: 2 прямоугольника на всю область рисования. 1-му background-color в стилях. 2-му fill(). И слоями через globalCompositeOperaion.

Comment: Зачем? Вам же нужно просто заполнить определённую область, определённым цветом - fillRect..

Comment: Для Анимации закрасить очищенную область.

Comment: Да делайте fillRect, или напишите свою функцию, которая в пятом параметре будет принимать цвет, а делать будет всего лишь заливку)

Comment: Вот с этим и проблема.Хотя бы набросок примерный?

Comment: Пример:  http://uupaa-js-spinoff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/uupaa-excanvas.js/demo/2_8_canvas_clearRect.html